# Access deeply nested object & build CSV file using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm fetching data using API and Im receiving an array of objects. I want to extract the Timestamp & Result to CSV file. Im unsure how could I access those objects and how to store them in CSV as Im a beginner of javascript, any advise would be very much appreciated

**My code:**

```
const url = "https://api2.branch.io/v1/query/analytics";
await fetch(url, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36",
            Accept: "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
      },
     body: JSON.stringify(data),
    })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
    Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
    console.log(data[key]);

    });
  })
.catch(error =>  {
  console.log(error);
})
};

//callback function
callApi();
```

**The output of the `console.log(data[key])`:**

```
[
  {
    timestamp: '2021-05-04T00:00:00.000+08:00',
    result: {
      last_attributed_touch_data_tilde_campaign: 'Broad',
      last_attributed_touch_data_tilde_advertising_partner_name: 'Google',
      last_attributed_touch_data_tilde_campaign_id: null,
      unique_count: 7483928
    }
  },
  {
    timestamp: '2021-05-04T00:00:00.000+08:00',
    result: {
      last_attributed_touch_data_tilde_campaign: 'Today',
      last_attributed_touch_data_tilde_advertising_partner_name: 'Yahoo',
      last_attributed_touch_data_tilde_campaign_id: null,
      unique_count: 43535345
    }
  },
  {
    timestamp: '2021-05-04T00:00:00.000+08:00',
    result: {
      last_attributed_touch_data_tilde_campaign: 'IOS',
      last_attributed_touch_data_tilde_advertising_partner_name: 'Facebook',
      last_attributed_touch_data_tilde_campaign_id: null,
      unique_count: 747473
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Where are you running this code ? In Node.js or in the browser ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to convert all data into CSV format. Here's one way you can do this, added comments to help you understand what is happening:

```js
// where the csv data will be saved to
let csv = [];
// loops through each object in the 'data' array
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  // this builds the CSV headers as the first line of the csv data
  // i === 0 makes sure to only target the first object in the 'data' array
  if (i === 0) {
    let title = [];
    // adds 'timestamp' key to the title array
    title.push('timestamp');
    // loops through all the 'result' keys, adds them to the growing title array
    for (let key in data[i].result) {title.push(key);}
    // format then collapses the array into a string, separated by commas to the csv array
    // ex: ['A', B'] turns into "A, B"
    csv.push(title.map(function(item) {return '' +item + '';}).join(', '));
  }
  // this builds the CSV data after the first line
  let row = [];
  // adds the 'timestamp' value to the row array
  row.push(data[i].timestamp);
  // loops through all the 'result' key's data, adds them to the growing row array
  for (let key in data[i].result) {row.push(data[i].result[key]);}
  // formats then collapses the array into a string, separated by commas to the csv array
  csv.push(row.map(function(item) {return '' +item + '';}).join(', '));
}
// collapses the csv array into a string, separated by a newline break
// ex: ['A', 'B'] turns into "A\nB"
csv = csv.join('\n');
```

Then you need to download the data in a CSV file format.

```js
function downloadAsCsv(csv, file_name) {
  var blob = new Blob([csv], {'type':'text/csv;charset=utf-8;'});
  // Internet Explorer 10+
  if (navigator.msSaveBlob) {window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, file_name);}
  else {
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    if (link.download !== undefined) { // feature detection
      // Browsers that support HTML5 download attribute
      var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      link.setAttribute('href', url);
      link.setAttribute('download', file_name);
      link.style.visibility = 'hidden';
      document.body.appendChild(link);
      link.click();
      document.body.removeChild(link);
    }
  }
}
```

Here's a full working example: https://jsfiddle.net/th5vejLc/